# How to stop Firebug from truncating strings in the console?

Tags: javascript, string, firefox, console, firebug

While debugging, I frequently dump strings and arrays to the console. But in some cases, Firebug chops up string values, making it hard to be sure of the result.

For example, this code in the console:

```
console.log ( [
    "123456789A123456789B123456789C123456789D123456789E123456789F123456789G",
    "123456789A123456789B123456789C123456789D123456789E123456789F123456789G"
] );
```

Yields:

```
[ "123456789A123456789B123...89E123456789F123456789G",
  "123456789A123456789B123...89E123456789F123456789G"
]
```

(Bad!)

A single string is okay.  This:

```
console.log ("123456789A123456789B123456789C123456789D123456789E123456789F123456789G");
```

Yields:

```
123456789A123456789B123456789C123456789D123456789E123456789F123456789G
```

as expected.

But, arrays and objects get shortened.
How do I stop this behavior?  Is this a bug?  (My Google-Fu has failed, so far.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firebug console shortening strings in array logged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359273/firebug-console-shortening-strings-in-array-logged)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, after pawing through the list of [**Firebug Preferences**](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Preferences) (there's 204 of those, right now, and not in an apparent order), I found `stringCropLength`.

It defaults to `50`, which makes sense, since the test strings were truncated to `123456789A123456789B123...89E123456789F123456789G`, which is 49 characters long.

Opening ***about:config*** and setting `extensions.firebug.stringCropLength` to 0, stopped the strings from being truncated!

Note that according to [Issue 5898: Introduce different string cropping preferences](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5898), this preference might affect a few things (for now).  But, so far, I've seen no ill effects from having this set to no "cropping".

Comment: Additionally, if you want Firebug to stop truncating Objects and Arrays to only 3 items, you can set `extensions.firebug.ObjectShortIteratorMax` to a high number. (`0` or `-1` don't work for this setting).

Answer (score 6):

Use `console.dir` instead of `console.log` - the output has a + near it which lets you expand the string.

Comment: Maaaaybe.  My next question would be, "How do I get those +'s expanded by default?"  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use console.dir("....") function instead of console.log("...")
Also u might be intersted to look at [firebug preferences](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Preferences)